# Jackson enum deserialize unwanted values to an "else" value

Tags: json, xml, kotlin, jackson

I'm trying to deserialize XML strings to this enum class

```
enum class FishType {
    @JsonProperty("fish-trout") TROUT,
    @JsonProperty("fish-salmon") SALMON,
    @JsonProperty("fish-halibut") HALIBUT,
    ...
}
```

There are a lot of types, but I'm only interested in making use of the first three types listed. Is there a way to deserialize any other string to a FishType.ELSE entry, rather than manually enter each possible string?

Comment: jackson only or with spring? If with spring, you can create a custom deserialiser.

Comment: I'm not using spring. Only jackson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@JsonEnumDefaultValue](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.13/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonEnumDefaultValue.html) works for XML too:

```kotlin
enum class FishType {
    @JsonProperty("fish-trout") TROUT,
    @JsonProperty("fish-salmon") SALMON,
    @JsonProperty("fish-halibut") HALIBUT,
    @JsonEnumDefaultValue ELSE
}

fun main() {
    val mapper = XmlMapper().apply {
        enable(DeserializationFeature.READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_USING_DEFAULT_VALUE)
    }
    println(mapper.readValue<FishType>("<FishType>fish-trout</FishType>")) //TROUT
    println(mapper.readValue<FishType>("<FishType>abc</FishType>")) //ELSE
}
```